# List of internet explorer properties in propertyChange event

Tags: internet-explorer, com

Does anyone know where I can find information on what the property strings mean that get passed when the propertyChange event fires? (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768348%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Such as: `265b75c1-4158-11d0-90f6-00c04fd497ea`

What type of property is that?

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do some research on this today and couldn't find anything either.  However, I question how useful these properties are anyway.

The two main events that fire for me on Windows 8.1 Update (IE11) are:

```
{265b75c1-4158-11d0-90f6-00c04fd497ea} 
- GetProperty always retrieves an I4 that is 0

{D0FCA420-D3F5-11CF-B211-00AA004AE837} 
- GetProperty always retrieves an IUnknown (variant type 13).
```

So the intriguing one is the IUnknown but you would have to play the QueryInterface guessing game to see what interfaces it supports.